# How to access client's account

Tags: algorithm, passwords, logic, client

*This is a logical request instead of code question.*

- All of my clients have seperate database. But front and back end works common. They signs in with client id (db-id).
- The passwords of the users encrypted with a different algorithm in the each databases.
- The algorithm keys of the passwords in the my customer's databases are automatically generated randomly.

I need to be able to sign in as a service account to my clients' databases. But I have to find a method that won't create security bugs.

*What I thought?*

- Creating a service account password with the same algorithm while creating the database. (Once this password is detected, it will create a security vulnerability for my client.)
- Access by leaving an open on the backend side. (Big vulnerability even if it's just office IP.)
- User creation with specified encryption algorithms. (To do this, I need to use the API key feature. I've to request to customer DB with this API key. The API key that I will create for myself may create a security vulnerability in the next days.)
- Authorized but not specified encrypted account. (Since this account will be our company e-mail address, it does not have a security vulnerability. However, since our client does not need SMTP, their system will not send emails.)
- Support request key (This seems the most logical. That they can generate a code so that I can access their account. This can create a user in the backend with the same password algorithm.)

As a result, when I think Google's API services, it creates a service account at first and can access us as it wishes. Of course, they don't think about client accounts, since everyone's account will crash in the vulnerability. :)

I'm curious about the opinions of those who think so well. Thank you for reading and for your reply.

Comment: You know what happens when you put all your eggs in one basket, right?

Breaking the separation between your different clients is probably a bad idea and it will hurt their security. Any such service can expose a route that you should be able to use via an authenticated call, to get the information you need from that service.

Comment: @NirAlfasi The system is protecting them now. But I can't access it. I'm looking for the most logical method I can access.

Comment: Are you programming this in Scheme? If not, why did you use that tag?

Comment: "The passwords of the users encrypted with a different algorithm in the each databases" -- why? It should be enough to use different usernames and passwords, you don't need to use a different encryption algorithm.

Comment: Just create an admin acount and give it grants to all the databases.

Comment: @Barmar, It works and I've so much customer. Also continuing to develope it. I intend that there is no security hole from the password that I will create. Because all actions are already logging. I can create an admin account as I want, but what is correct that the customer creates that account, not me. Or how should it be if I am creating it? That's my question already.